Evaluating $\langle k'; j,m_j'| S_z |k;j,m_j\rangle$ Using the Projection Lemma
A vector under rotation has the following property: $[\hat{J_i},\hat{V_j}] = i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{V_k}$. Furthermore the projection lemma is defined as the following:
$$\langle k'; j,m_j'| \vec{V} |k;j,m_j\rangle = \frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{V} \cdot \vec{J}) \vec{J} | k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)} . \tag{2.5.15}$$
On page 24 of this note  it is
claimed that
$$\langle k'; j,m_j'| S_z |k;j,m_j\rangle = \hbar m_j \frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{S} \cdot \vec{J})| k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)}.  \tag{2.5.17}$$
I have been starring at this for hours, and it is not obvious where the $\hbar m$ is coming from, given that it is $J_z |j,m_j\rangle = \hbar m_j |j,m_j\rangle$.
Secondly, shouldn't $(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{J} ) = S_zJ_z$, since we are only analyzing the $S_z$ part and not the full $\vec{S}$ vector? I feel I may be misinterpreting notation, so any help is appreciated.

$\langle\hat{\mathbf S}\rangle = \frac{\langle(\hat{\mathbf S}\cdot \hat{\mathbf J})\hat{\mathbf J}\rangle}{\langle\hat{\mathbf J}^2\rangle}$ so $\langle\hat{S_z}\rangle = \frac{\langle(\hat{\mathbf S}\cdot \hat{\mathbf J})\hat{J_z}\rangle}{\langle\hat{\mathbf J}^2\rangle}$

Indeed, you are misreading the notation involved. $(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{J} ) = S_xJ_x+S_yJ_y+ S_zJ_z$, and not just the last term, as you are imagining—how could you? These operators are well-defined and non-vanishing.
Plugging into  (2.5.15), then, collapses to
$$\langle k'; j,m_j'| \hat  S_z |k;j,m_j\rangle = \frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\hat {S} \cdot \hat {J})  \hat J_z | k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)} , $$amounting to (2.5.17).


$$\langle k'; j,m_j'| \vec{V} |k;j,m_j\rangle = \frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{V} \cdot \vec{J}) \vec{J} | k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)} . \tag{2.5.15}$$
On page 24 of this note  it is
claimed that
$$\langle k'; j,m_j'| S_z |k;j,m_j\rangle = \hbar m_j \frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{S} \cdot \vec{J})| k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)}.  \tag{2.5.17}$$
I have been starring at this for hours, and it is not obvious where the $\hbar m$ is coming from, given that it is $J_z |j,m_j\rangle = \hbar m_j |j,m_j\rangle$.

Your Eq. (2.5.15) holds for each cartesian component individually. So,
$$\langle k'; j,m_j'| V_x |k;j,m_j\rangle = \frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{V} \cdot \vec{J}) J_x | k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)}$$
and
$$\langle k'; j,m_j'| V_y |k;j,m_j\rangle = \frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{V} \cdot \vec{J}) J_y | k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)}$$
and
$$\langle k'; j,m_j'| V_z |k;j,m_j\rangle = \frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{V} \cdot \vec{J}) J_z | k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)}\tag{A}$$
$$
=\hbar m_j\frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{V} \cdot \vec{J})| k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)}\;,\tag{B}
$$
where, yes, you are right, you use $J_z| k; j, m_j \rangle = \hbar m_j| k; j, m_j \rangle$.
If you take $V_z = S_z$ in Eq. (B) above you get
$$
\langle k'; j,m_j'| S_z |k;j,m_j\rangle = \hbar m_j\frac{\langle k'; j,m_j'| (\vec{S} \cdot \vec{J}) | k; j, m_j \rangle }{\hbar^2 j(j+1)}\;\tag{C}$$

Secondly, shouldn't $(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{J} ) = S_zJ_z$,

No. The $(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{J} )$ is the usual dot product, nothing more.
